# How to parse a data organized in a tree?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm reading an .xml file and try to parse the data. The goal is to simplify the data. The input may look something like this (`ValueX`/`ValueY` are far more complex than a simple string, e.g. it may be references to other parts of the xml file):

```xml
<node>
    <name>rootNode</name>
    <node>
        <name>Main</name>
        <node>
            <name>Child1</name>
            <valueX>abc</valueX>
            <valueY>def</valueY>
        </node>
    </node>
</node>
```

My current approach looks like this:

```
class Parser {
    public SimpleModel parse(Node rootNode) {
        Node mainNode = getMainNode(rootNode);
        ValueX valueX = inspectMainNode(mainNode);

        SimpleModel model = new SimpleModel();
        model.setValueX(valueX);
        return model;
    }

    private ValueX inspectMainNode(Node mainNode) {
        ValueX valueX = /* acquire the value */
        return valueX;
    }
    /* ... */
}
```

How should I refactor this code if `ValueY` would also be needed?
Currently the best things I can think of are these two solutions:

1) Pass the model object to the inspect method, e.g. `private void inspectMainMode(Node mainNode, SimpleModel model);`. Downside of this is that I have to pass the model object to many methods and the methods returns void => harder to test.

2) Create two methods which only acquire `ValueX`/`ValueY`, e.g. `private ValueX getValueX(Node mainNode);`. Downside: there could be code duplication if the methods have to do similar things

What would you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Why not  make a function that returns a string composed of those 2 values and use a split function on it?

Comment: @tudoricc The values are not strings, they are complex objects, lists, maps, etc.

Comment: I deleted my comment because after I wrote it I realised what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO if the only thing that has changed is that you have to return 2 values (or n >= 2), create a class containing the two (n) values and return an instance of that class :

```
class Values {
    ValueX valueX;
    ValueY valueY;
    // constructors, setters, getters, equals and hashcode ommitted for brevity ...
}
...
private ValueX inspectMainNode(Node mainNode) {
    ValueX valueX = /* acquire the value */
    ValueY valueY = /* acquire the value */
    return new Values(valueX, valueY);
}
/* ... */
```

That way the global structure of your code remains unchanged, as is the design of your test methods.

Comment: I don't like the idea of creating a Wrapper object for the purpose of returning more than one value. The values aren't necessarily related. Furthermode your suggested `Values` class would then resemble my `SimpleModel` class (for some parts at least).